# UAE Phone number regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
^(?:[\+971|00971|0]*)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})
```

which would accept these phone numbers

```
009715060403341
05060403341
+9715060403341
```

However, I dont want to accept these numbers

```
009712060403341
02060403341
+9712060403341
```

So the second non capturing group should not be starting with a 2. Thats the condition.

Can anyone give a help to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead to check for the number which was matched by the second non-capturing won't be start by 2. And remove the square brackets which was present inside the first non-capturing group.

```
^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?!2)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hE9iF2/1)

**OR**

Simply remove `2` from the second non-capturing group.

```
^(?:\+971|00971|0)((?:3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hE9iF2/2)

Comment: Thank you @Avinash for your great help - could you let me know how should I put OR condition for negative lookahead ? ie, if I dont want to start the second non-capturing group also by 4?

Comment: `^(?:\+971|00971|0)(?!2|4)((?:2|3|4|5|6|7|9|50|51|52|55|56)[0-9]{7,})$`, accept if this answer helps..